# adfuller number of lags returned

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, statsmodels

I have the following code snippet for performing the adfuller test on my time series

```
def dickey_fuller(series):
    X = series
    result = adfuller(X, regression='ct')
    print('ADF Statistic: %f' % result[0])
    print('p-value: %f' % result[1])
    print('Lags used: %d' % result[2])
    print('Critical Values:')
    for key, value in result[4].items():
        print('%s: %.3f' % (key, value))
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
```

Those are the adfuller values by default:

```
statsmodels.tsa.stattools.adfuller(x, maxlag=None, regression='c', autolag='AIC', store=False, regresults=False)
```

As cited in the statsmodels docs, when we have `autolag='AIC'` it will choose the number of lags that minimize the information criterion.

The following is a sample output of my run of this test on my data:

```
ADF Statistic: -7.359845
p-value: 0.000000
Lags used: 7
Critical Values:
1%: -4.021
5%: -3.441
10%: -3.145
```

I am interested in including the appropriate number of lags as column in my data, and here the used number of lags is 7. In this case, shall I take all lags from 1 up to 7 or shall I take only the 7th lag?

Or in other words, is the returned number of lags the lag length or the best lag taken ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.adfuller.html) it returns the number of lag**S** used. But typically, when talking about such models, somethink like : AR(2) refers to an autogressive model using two lags. If you use *some* lags like every other seventh or twelveth lag, it's a seasonal component.

Comment: Thank you @NaturalFrequency, so by that I can safely choose all lags up to the 7th ? I want to insert these 7 lags as columns in my data.

Comment: @Loulou No problem! Don't forget to mark to question as "answered" if that worked for you

Comment: Sure, Thank you!